# Push Notification Service in Android for app build with Phone-Gap

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, google-cloud-messaging

How to do with Push Notification Service in Android for app build with Phone-Gap and Sencha Touch?
How to use WCF Service for back-end process (Connecting Google Message Service)?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [Sencha Touch Extensions for Windows Azure](https://market.sencha.com/extensions/sencha-touch-extensions-for-windows-azure) which has push notifications built into it (via Windows Azure).

- [Video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Episode-126-Using-Sencha-With-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services)
- [Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch-azure/1.0.0/#!/guide/mobile_services_push)